# ostream overloading with for loop, no return value

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, operator-keyword, ostream

I am trying to overload my ostream operator<<, and in the body of the function I want to use a for-loop. Memory is a class I made, and its internal structure is a vector. So basically, I just want to go through the vector and print out everything that's in it when I pass Memory to an output-stream.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Memory& mem) 
{
    int curr(mem.get_current());
    for (int i = 0; i <= curr; ++i) 
    {    
        return out << mem.mem_[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Compiler says that there is no return value, in a function returning non-void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current version:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Memory& mem) 
{
    int curr(mem.get_current());
    for (int i = 0; i <= curr; ++i)
    {    
        return out << mem.mem_[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If `curr == 0`, nothing ever gets returned.  You need to always return `out`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Memory& mem) 
{
    int curr(mem.get_current());
    for (int i = 0; i <= curr; ++i) 
    {    
        out << mem.mem_[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return out; // outside the loop, so it always gets returned!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Memory& mem) {
  int curr(mem.get_current());
  for (int i = 0; i <= curr; ++i) {
    out << mem.mem_[i] << std::endl;
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: @JN11 there is clearly a return value in the code in my answer.

Comment: You're right, stupid mistake. I feel dumb now :p
Thanks anyway